# Apply a function to pandas DataFrame with a condition to check for `NaNs`

Tags: python, pandas

I have `Null` and `NaNs` in one of the pandas DataFrame columns. I'd like to `apply` with a condition to check for `NaN` in the column and store the return from the function into a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 9, NaN],
                   'Col2': [1, 3, 5]}) 

def sample_func(v1, v2, token):    
    # call API 
    r = cl_apicall(v1, v2, token)
    return r

# mock api call
def cl_apicall(v1, v2, token):
    return f"{v1},-{v2}-{token}"

# Apply function
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: sample_func(x['Col1'], x['Col2'], 'xxxxxx'), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Result

```
   Col1  Col2          new_col
0   1.0     1  1.0,-1.0-xxxxxx
1   9.0     3  9.0,-3.0-xxxxxx
2   NaN     5  nan,-5.0-xxxxxx
```

How do I write the `apply` statement for only `NaNs` or `Null` in `col1` values only? Note, function is simplified for reproducibility.

Expected result:

```
 Col1  Col2          new_col
0   1.0     1  
1   9.0     3  
2   NaN     5  nan,-5.0-xxxxxx
```

i.e only `.apply` the function to rows where `Col1` is `NaN`.

Comment: I made a small modification to make the code runnable and print the result. I'm not sure what you want for rows that are not NaN. Can you add a "wanted" section with the results edited to reflect your goals?

Comment: @tdelaney I added a 'Expected Result` section. Basically, need to only apply the function to rows where `Col1` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter for the rows you want, apply the function and then assign to the new column. Pandas will fill the missing rows with `NaN`. This is usually more efficient than running apply for each row.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 9, NaN],
                   'Col2': [1, 3, 5]}) 

def sample_func(v1, v2, token):
    # call API 
    r = cl_apicall(v1, v2, token)
    return r

# mock api call
def cl_apicall(v1, v2, token):
    return f"{v1},-{v2}-{token}"

# Apply function
#df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: sample_func(x['Col1'], x['Col2'], 'xxxxxx'), axis = 1)
df['new_col'] = df[df['Col1'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: sample_func(x['Col1'], x['Col2'], 'xxxxxx'), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Result

```
   Col1  Col2          new_col
0   1.0     1              NaN
1   9.0     3              NaN
2   NaN     5  nan,-5.0-xxxxxx
```